# Removed object and created new object with same name, keeps referencing old object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Had a `NSObject` `userInfo`. I removed it (reference only, still have the .h/.m file on the HDD) in Xcode and I created a `NSManagedObject` `userInfo`.

Xcode still thinks I want the old `userInfo` object instead of the new one.  How can I let Xcode know there is a new userInfo, is it stored in a cache somewhere?

EDIT:

When I right click the object and select Jump to Definition, it takes me to the old object, not the new object.

Comment: Tried a "clean project"?

Comment: I didn't, but just did. Didn't sove the issue. To be more precise, when writing the code, the attributes are not popping up in the auto-complete list.

Comment: Have you deleted the previous object completely?

Comment: I removed the reference, I did not delete the actual .h/.m files.

Comment: Ok, I moved the files out of the project and relaunched Xcode and the project and its now finding the correct definitions. I wanted to keep the files in the project in case I needed to look at them again in the future. Not happy wit the solution, but its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try cleaning the project(Shift + Command + K).

2.If that does not help, you can reset your simulator.

3.Also try quitting your X-Code & launch the project again.

Comment: Ok, I tried all three and didn't solve the issue.  To be more precise, when writing the code, the new attributes are not popping up in the auto-complete list thing.

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator?

Comment: You deleted d app & re-installed it?
If that does not help, then probably you might be over riding the value of userinfo' somewhere.
Any chance to post the code?

Comment: In the middle of a rewrite and can't easily compile it. When I try to access an attribute, say userInfo.lastName, the attribute lastName is not working (name is a new attrbute in the new object).

Comment: Try debugging with the help of memory location. It helps to understand whether you are re-initializing the object again or not.

Answer (score 0):

userInfo.. is a singleton.... thats why you keep receiving the same value

if you want a different userinfo.. then use 'userInformation' or other identifier.